# Using Google Sheets As A Backend Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

I volunteer at nonprofit, and we currently run our website through Squarespace. We have hundreds of web pages set up to sponsor our children. Every few months when we want to update their personal information, we have to go into each web page and retype all the information. We keep all our information in a google excel sheet.

My question is: Am I able to link cells from the Google Sheet to specific values on each child's webpage? That way, when the excel sheet is updated (favorite activity, favorite color, grade, age...etc.), it can all be updated through the Google Sheet instead of having to first update the Google Sheet, and then updating each individual webpage. I've been researching this for days now, and I feel like it may be possibly with JQuery, but I feel very limited with Squarespace's capabilities. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't Firebase then better?

Comment: Check out [sheetrock](https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock/); maybe it has the functionality you need?

Comment: I think Sheetrock is the closest to what I'm looking for. Thanks for the suggestion! My biggest struggle though is how to implement that with Squarespace. Each child in our orphanage has an individual sponsorship page, and all their data is kept on a Google Sheet (i.e. favorite color, favorite food....etc.) So I need to link their specific cells on the Google Sheet to their individual web page. That way, when we update the Google Sheet, their web page will update automatically. I don't know if it's even possible with Squarespace, but I want to try everything possible before I call it quits.

Comment: The short answer is no.

"We have hundreds of web pages"

There is no way to even manage this many pages in Squarespace

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes.

You can use a google sheet as a database for any application, update and manipulate data. 
I have been doing that for a long time now. Google has recently released its **Google Sheet API V4 (the current)** the last version.

I followed this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts
. On the left panel, you can choose the programming language you wish to develop under Quickstart.
It supports: 
PHP. 
Android.
Java.
Node.js.
Python. 
Ruby.
Perl. 
Go
iOS
.NET

The trick is that you need to set an ID for each record which refer to the line number. Your column should also be fixed. This is because queries in Google Sheet API refer to the column number and row number. (Known as index).

Comment: This answer isn't at all relevant to Squarespace.

– You don't have server or db access..

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following repository that i once used to do this same thing.
https://github.com/souparno/google-sheet-database

Some of the api calls might be old and needs to be updated.

- this is a quick answer, i will update more when i get some time